# Get hashtag from string and get into meta keywords and tags

Tags: php, html, preg-replace, meta-tags, hashtag

I'm creating a kind of a blog sharing link. Basically, for each link i would extract hashtag from post string and put it into a meta tags and keywords.

So, string normally is like this

```
#helloworld #test #video #youtube Bon Iver are the best daily surprise :D
```

Now, how can i get only hashtags and insert into a string like this ?

```
$hashtags = helloworld,test,video,youtube
```

And after insert hashtags in meta tag

```
<meta name="keywords" content="<? echo $hashtags ?>" >
<meta name="tags" content="<? echo $hashtags ?>">
```

Actually i used this script to remove "#" and put ","

```
$hashclear = preg_replace('/#([A-Za-z0-9]+)/', '$1,', $post);
```

How can i get these ? Any ideas ?

Comment: ...and *no one* could be bothered to provide a non-regex answer? 

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
$str = '#helloworld #test #video #youtube Bon Iver are the best daily surprise :D';

preg_match_all('/#([^\s]+)/', $str, $matches);

$hashtags = implode(',', $matches[1]);

var_dump($hashtags);
```

Comment: it's exactly what i wanted :D and if i would do the same thing leaving only string and removing hashtag ? I think this way preg_replace('/#([A-Za-z0-9]+)/', '', $post); but i'm sure that there's a best clean way, any ideas ?

Comment: What's the result you expect then if you just leaving string only?

Comment: For example i would extract only "Bon Iver are the best daily surprise :D"

Comment: That seems to be a clean way to me. You could propably replace multiple spaces in the string with one single space (`preg_replace('/ {2,}/', ' ', $post)`). But your `preg_replace('/#([A-Za-z0-9]+)/', null, $post)` is fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
$hashTag = "#helloworld #test #video #youtube Bon Iver are the best daily surprise :D";

$str = str_replace('#', '', 
    preg_replace('/(?:#[\w-]+\s*)+$/', '', $hashTag);

echo $str;
```