# Finding Hashtags in String

Tags: php

I am trying to find all the hashtags in a String

Example String:

> Hello World #Hello #World #Hello-World #Hello_World #Test-Tag

I tried using below code:

```
preg_match_all('/#([^\s]+)/', $postbody, $matches);
    $tags = implode(',', $matches[1]);
    var_dump($tags);
```

The result is

> Hello,World,Hello-World,Hello_World,Test-Tag

How can I make it end at any characters besides A-Z, a-z, and 0-9

My goal output is

> Hello, World, Test

I would like it to stop right before it reaches a character that isn't a letter or number also not print duplicates.

Reference:
[Get hashtag from string reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976571/get-hashtag-from-string-and-get-into-meta-keywords-and-tags)

Comment: Is this what you want? https://www.tinywebhut.com/regex/10

Comment: @Saral I want that but to only return "Hello, World, Test"

Comment: use `A-Za-z0-9` in preg_match_all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[a-zA-Z0-9]` regex to get only letters and numbers.
And later, use [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to filter out duplicate matches

```
$postbody = 'Hello World #Hello #World #Hello-World #Hello_World #Test-Tag';

preg_match_all('/#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/', $postbody, $matches);
if(!empty($matches)){
   $tags = implode(',', array_unique($matches[1]));
   var_dump($tags);
}
```

Output: `string(16) "Hello,World,Test"`

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!